# BuddyPress Xprofile check if user can view field

Tags: buddypress

I use the following code to get a custom BuddyPress Xprofile field:

```
<?php if($field = bp_get_profile_field_data('field=field_name')) : ?>
<p><?php echo $field; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But how can I check if the current viewer has the permission to view the field (from the visibility setting who the user can set)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question with [support from the members from the BuddyPress forum](http://buddypress.org/support/topic/xprofile-check-if-user-can-view-field/). The function that I needed was xprofile_get_field_data().

Here my code:

```
<?php $hidden_fields = bp_xprofile_get_hidden_fields_for_user(); ?>
<?php if(xprofile_get_field_data('field_name') && !in_array(xprofile_get_field_id_from_name('field_name'), $hidden_fields)) : ?>
<p><?php echo xprofile_get_field_data ('field_name'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```