# Using xprofile_insert_field

Tags: user-meta, profiles

I'm trying to add a xProfile to BuddyPress, but I don't know where but my snippet is not working. I have tried so many stuff, but I just can't get it right.

Hope you can help, here's the latest version of my snippet:

```
add_action('bp_init', 'field_xprofile_twitter');

function field_xprofile_twitter()
{

xprofile_insert_field( $xfield_args );
global $bp;
$xfield_args =  array (
           field_group_id  => 1,
           name            => 'Twitter',
           can_delete      => false,
           field_order  => 1,
           is_required     => false,
           type            => 'textbox'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does work. It's just that you are declaring $xfield_args after you have made the call xprofile_insert_field( $xfield_args );

it should look like this

```
add_action('bp_init', 'field_xprofile_twitter');

function field_xprofile_twitter()
{

   global $bp;
   $xfield_args =  array (
           field_group_id  => 1,
           name            => 'Twitter',
           can_delete      => false,
           field_order     => 1,
           is_required     => false,
           type            => 'textbox'
    );

   xprofile_insert_field( $xfield_args );
}
```

Comment: It worked but it's creating a Twitter field with every single page load. Anyway to stop it?

Comment: If you have this in the functions.php file it will run every time you load a page. [Try looking at this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114820/buddypress-xprofile-check-if-user-can-view-field), write an if statement to check if it exits `if(!in_array(xprofile_get_field_id_from_name('field_name'), $hidden_fields){ execute code }`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use this condition if above condition is not working :

```
if(!xprofile_get_field_id_from_name('Twitter')){
    xprofile_insert_field( $xfield_args );
  }
```